# iTunes search API returns different app icons for 60x60 and 1024x1024

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

At first, I have to say that I am not sure whether I should ask this question on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or on [AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com). I decided to use AskDifferent because this question is not programming-specific.

My question:
I use the [iTunes search API](https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html) to get information about some apps. I use the iTunes lookup (`http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=[some app id]`) URL to get this information. The return dictionary contains two links for the app icon:

- `artworkUrl60`
- `artworkUrl512`

The urls after the specific links point to the app icon.
The problem is that the image returned for the `artworkUrl60` key is not the same as the image returned for the `artworkUrl512` key.

**Example:** (I'm sorry that the second image is so much bigger, that's because it's the big artwork)
Vizzywig 4K
`artworkUrl60`: [image]
`artworkUrl512`: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps can have different artwork. Whilst Apple recommends simply scaling your app icon for iTunes Artwork, there's nothing preventing them from being different images.

Comment: I understand that, but why should somebody upload different icons for the same app?

Comment: @Lukas They may wish to have a more detailed icon, or a different colour scheme, or any other reason. There's no concrete answer and depends entirely on the developer.

Comment: @Lukas It's the developers choice. It's not like every developer does the same.